# how to change the name of a variable to be called using string manipulation in R?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to change the name of a variable to be called in r on the fly.

For example, dataframe trades_long_final has many columns "prob_choice1" and  "prob_choice2", ...  "prob_choiceN" and "col1", "col2", ... "colN".

I want to change the value of each on the fly.

For example,

```
trades_long_final$"prob_choice1"[1] = 10 and 
trades_long_final$"prob_choice2"[1] = 10
```

works

but not

```
trades_long_final$gsub("1","2","prob_choice1")[1] = 10
```

as a way to call trades_long_final$"prob_choice2"[1] by substituting the 1 in prob_choice1 with a 2 because I get the error

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

I need this to work because I need to loop over the columns using something like trades_long_final$gsub("i","2","prob_choicei")[1] in a loop for all i.

Thank you so much for your help. It must be a command I don't know how to use...

Comment: A better approach may be `trades_long_final[1,grep('^prob_choice', names(trades_long_final))] <- 10`  But, it is not clear why you need a loop.  Perhaps, some more details would have been helpful.  If you need to change the first row of all the columns `trades_long_final[1,] <- 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$`, you can use `[` to change the variable name and assign the value in one line.

```
 trades_long_final[,gsub("1","2","prob_choice1")][1] <- 10
```

But, it is not clear why you need to do this.  Simply

```
 trades_long_final[1, "prob_choice2"] <- 10
```

would be easier.  From the description, "prob_choice2" is already a column in the dataset.  So, it is confusing.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
trades_long_final <- data.frame(prob_choice1 =runif(10), 
    prob_choice2=rnorm(10), col1=rnorm(10,10), col2=rnorm(10,30))
```

Answer (score 0):

as akrun said, the way to do it was to use `[` so that the way I did it was:

```
for (k in 1:numtrades){

        trades_long_final[[paste("prob_choice", k, sep="")]] = 
    {some complex procedure...}

}
```